# Tap twice to highlight checkmark in collection view

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicollectionview

I have a collection view where you can tap the cell to enlarge the image and tap it the enlarged image to dismiss it, on each cell i also have a selectable checkmark so you can choose to download the selected images later. The code almost works apart from the fact that sometimes i have to select or deselect the checkmark twice. I dont really understand what im missing but here is my code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "photoCell", for: indexPath) as! PhotoCell
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(checkmarkWasTapped(_ :)))

    cell.backgroundColor = .clear
    cell.imageView.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagesURLArray[indexPath.row].path)
    cell.checkmarkView.checkMarkStyle = .GrayedOut
    cell.checkmarkView.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.checkmarkView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    return cell
}

func checkmarkWasTapped(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {

    let checkmarkView = sender.view as! SSCheckMark
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: checkmarkView.tag, section: 0)

    let imageURL = imagesURLArray[indexPath.row]

    if checkmarkView.checked == true {

        checkmarkView.checked = false
        selectedImagesArray.remove(at: selectedImagesArray.index(of: imageURL)!)
    } else {

        checkmarkView.checked = true
        selectedImagesArray.append(imageURL)
    }

    collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    addZoomedImage(indexPath.row)
    addGestureToImage()
    addBackGroundView()

    view.addSubview(selectedImage)
}
```

Any help would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have a problem when you make scrolling on collection view, collection view reloads every cell and you don't have any information about latest state of checkview.

Usually I store an array of bool(size of number of elements in collection view, you can create easily after load your model) so every time user double tap on checkmark view I change take the index of collection view cell and change bool array elements to true.

```
var boolArray = [Bool]()
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "photoCell", for: indexPath) as! PhotoCell
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(checkmarkWasTapped(_ :)))

    cell.backgroundColor = .clear
    cell.imageView.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagesURLArray[indexPath.row].path)

        if(boolArray[indexPath.row]){
            cell.checkmarkView.checked = false
        }
        else{
            cell.checkmarkView.checked = true
        }

    cell.checkmarkView.checkMarkStyle = .GrayedOut
    cell.checkmarkView.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.checkmarkView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    return cell
}
```

It could be an ugly solution but I believe it'll work.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying, will the if statement youve added not swap the selection on each reload? is it supposed to say `if !(boolArray[indexPath.row]){`

Comment: If user haven't bookmarked the cell before boolArray[indexPath.row] will be false and so checkmarkView will be unchecked when cell loaded. Else it'll be checked. If your checkmarkView worked like that?

Comment: if i fill the bool array with false in viewdidload and use`if !(boolArray[indexPath.row])` they all are unchecked but when i select the check then uncheck immediately, if i do the same but with `if (boolArray[indexPath.row])` then they all are checked and nothing happens when i select them.

Comment: ahhh, i needed to update the bool array in `checkmarkWasTapped()` and use `if !(boolArray[indexPath.row])` and now it works. Thank you for your help!